# ReactDOM.render does not update containers props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dom

I have a container containing some html with a `<div id="ID"></div>`. I have a react stateful component that I want to render in that div using

```
React.render(<ChildComponent data={this.props.data} />, document.getElementById('ID'))
```

When I call an action in childcomponent and udate the redux state, the props of the parent container do not update, only the ChildComponent re-renders with old values. Those props get updated when I refresh the page.

What is the solution to this ? Is there any other way to render React component in html so that the props can be updated with new props ?

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing `ReactDOM.render`, even if you are doing that you won't be passing data as `this.props.data` since you wouldn't have this inside a React class. Try to add a working jsFiddle that we can see

Comment: I'm not completely sure but, you don't have to put HTML elements inside the container you are rendering the app, it is like rendering the app in the body: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375

Comment: Here is my gist :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d9932ad66e965ef812c0737b304024dd

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code for `<ChildComponent>` and its parent? There are a number of things you might be doing wrong but the thing that stands out is that it looks like you're rendering  separately from its parent instead of as a child "prop" of its parent, like so:

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent />
</ParentComponent>
```

The official docs also have a lot of examples on how to get started: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indirectly yes. But first see my code here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d9932ad66e965ef812c0737b304024dd